# Showing outline or border in Samsung S8 and Google Pixel

Tags: html, css, border, google-pixel

I am struggling an issue in Google Pixel and Samsung S8 with a border like thing around the div. We have to run that with Google Pixel or samsung S8 to see the issue. Attacing an image for better understanding[image]

Js fiddle for code https://jsfiddle.net/s23xdks7/4/

```css
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0;
}
.child__01{
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child__01">

  </div>
  <div class="child__01">

  </div>
  <div class="child__01">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think that is not a border. you gave a red background color for that parent div.if that background color is not relevant there just remove that css.

Comment: This is just an example, I have background image for the parent and PNG images inside the child div. so it's showing a border/outline/space like in the example. can anybody help on this?

Comment: `33.3%`: did you try with more significant digits like `33.333%` or better let browsers do the calculation: `calc(100% / 3)`? 3 significant digits with a 1,440 px wide device may lead to rounding problems, maybe

Comment: @FelipeAls I had tried that already